# GetStream- Without following feed?

Tags: getstream-io

I need the public flat feed. For instance, the user named 'public'.It does not have follower or following anyone, if user:public posts any activity, it can reach all of the users timeline, how to do that?

I have tried the user:global but without following the user:global, did not get or retrieve the activity of user:global

Answer (score 3):

While Stream does not provide a global feed there are multiple ways you could implement a public global feed:

1. Define a 'global' feed (e.g. `user:global`) and follow that feed by all user feeds on user creation

```js
const user = await client.currentUser.getOrCreate({
    name: "John Doe", 
    occupation: "Software Engineer",
    gender: 'male'
});
await client.feed("user").follow("user", "global");
```

This is enough if you just want to expose users to global feed content.

2. Use `to` field in activity to deliver the content to all interested feeds (https://getstream.io/docs/#targetting) but it has a limit of 100 targets.